# Is there any shortlink for WordPress Development?

Tags: feature-request

A user profile URL in WordPress Development is too long for sharing:

```
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/[userid]/[username]
```

I know it can be shortened up to the user id:

```
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/[userid]
```

I also aware that, a question can be shared by the following manner:

```
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/[q/a]/[itemid]/[sharerid]
```

But is there any tinyURL of the first part of our site? Like:

```
http://se.wpse/...
```

If "no", then can the StackExchange Network create one for their sites? So that we can share tiny links instead of a lengthy one.

Comment: The idea was [actively decided against](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110407/please-add-question-and-answer-shortlinks-with-site-names-to-the-s-tk-url-shorte).

Comment: @cjbj hmm. so it's a duplicate, and against too.

Answer (score 8):

There is a short URL for root of the site: [s.tk/wp](http://s.tk/wp)

Alas, it doesn't process anything nested.

`/users/[userid]` can be further shortened to `/u/[userid]` but it doesn't help much with bulky domain.

Comment: _Alas, it doesn't process anything nested._ :(